# iOS - SBJson4Parser - +parserWithBlock:allowMultiRoot:unwrapRootArray:errorHandler: synchronous?

Tags: ios, sbjson

I m using SBJson version 4.0.0.

I parse my JSON by invoke this function (from SBJson documentation):

```
+ (id)parserWithBlock:(SBJson4ValueBlock)block
       allowMultiRoot:(BOOL)allowMultiRoot
      unwrapRootArray:(BOOL)unwrapRootArray
         errorHandler:(SBJson4ErrorBlock)eh;
```

And My code is:

```
SBJson4Parser *parser = [SBJson4Parser parserWithBlock:^(id item, BOOL *stop) {
    NSObject *itemObject = item;
    
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        self.activitiesDict = (NSDictionary*)itemObject;
    }
}
                                        allowMultiRoot:NO
                                       unwrapRootArray:NO
                                          errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                          }];
[parser parse:data];
```

Does the block that I passed to parserWithBlock function is synchronous?

Can I count that the lines after     `[parser parse:data];` will run after the parser work?

Comment: Yes - the blocks here are called during the synchronous processing of the JSON data to provide feedback on progress and ability to abort part way through.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `parse:` method is synchronous.